# Specifying model Meta data through decorators (django)

Tags: python, django, decorator

The problem: I wish to use Postgres Schemas to separate the tables of different parts of my django app at database level.

#### Aside

You can skip this section, but I think it's helpful to add context to these things. My app is working on a database of existing data (stored in the `public` schema, helpfully), which it's very important I don't modify. As such, I want to separate "my" data into a separate schema (to which django will be given read/write/play in the sand access), while restricting access to the `public` schema to read-only. I originally tried to solve this by separating my data out into a separate database and using database routing, but it turns out (if I'd only read the documentation) that django doesn't support cross database dependencies (which is fair enough I suppose), and my models have foreign keys into the read-only data.

#### The meat

There exists a workaround for Django's lack of schema support (which you can read about [here](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6148)) which is to specify the `db_table` attribute in your model's meta, like so:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    attribute1 = models.CharField()

     #Fool django into using the schema
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'schema_name\".\"table_name'
```

This is great, but I didn't really want to have to write this for every single model in my app - for a start, it doesn't seem pythonic, and also there's every chance of me forgetting when I have to add a new model.

My solution was the following snippet:

```
def SchemaBasedModel(cls):
    class Meta:
        db_table = '%s\".\"%s' % (schema_name, cls.__name__)
    cls.Meta = Meta
    return cls

@SchemaBasedModel
class MyModel(models.Model):
    attribute1 = models.CharField()
    ...
```

When I then run `python manage.py shell` I get the following:

```
>>> from myapp import models
>>> myModel = models.MyModel
>>> myModel.Meta.db_table
'myschema"."mymodel'
>>>
```

"Looks good to me," I thought. I then ran: `python manage.py sqlall myapp`. Sadly, this yielded the original table names - that is, the table names as they were *before* I applied this meta info. When I went back and applied the meta info "by hand" (i.e. by adding `Meta` inner classes to all my models), things were as expected (new table names).

I was hoping somebody could enlighten me as to what was going on here? Or, more usefully, what's the "*right*" way to do this? I thought the decorator pattern I've talked about here would be just the ticket for this problem, but apparently it's a non-starter. How can I quickly and easily apply this meta info to all my models, without typing it out every single time?

**Edit**: Perhaps I was a little unclear when I asked this - I'm as interested in know what's "actually going on" (i.e. why things aren't working the way I thought they would - what did I misunderstand here?) as how to solve my problem (clear separation of "my" data from legacy data, preferably on a schema level - but it's not the end of the world if I have to dump everything into the `public` schema and manage permissions on a per-table basis).

**Second Edit**: The accepted answer doesn't necessarily tell me what I really want to know, but it *is* probably the right solution for the actual problem. Short answer: don't do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I didn't really want to have to write this for every single model in my app - 
>   for a start, it doesn't seem pythonic,

That's false.  Some things have to be written down explicitly.  "Explicit is better than Implicit".

> and also there's every chance of me forgetting when I have to add a new model

That's false, also.

You won't "forget".

Bottom Line:  Don't mess with this kind of thing.  Simply include the 2 lines of code explicitly where necessary.

You don't have that many tables.

You won't forget.

Also, be sure to use DB permissions.  Grant SELECT permission only on your "legacy" tables (the tables you don't want to write to). Then you can't write to them.

Comment: That doesn't really explain what's going on here though. I have resorted to explicitly adding the meta to every single model, but I really think a decorator would be neater. Even if not, the question still stands: what is it that means this doesn't work the way I thought it would? And until Schema support makes it into Django proper, what's the "right" way to make use of them, preferably on a per-app basis?

Comment: "I really think a decorator would be neater".  That's debatable.  A subclass would be neater.  A decorator is not very neat at all since you must explicitly add the decorator to every single model.  "what's the "right" way to make use of them?"  By "them" do you mean explicit table names?  They're totally supported.   By "them" do you mean schema names?  We use them as part of the Django settings in the DATABASE identification.

Comment: I thought about subclassing, but I'd still have to over-ride the db_table field in every model, so it doesn't seem to make a difference (unless I've got this wrong?). On schema names: When you say you use them as part of Django settings in the DATABASE identification, you don't mean the DATABASES dictionary in the project's settings.py do you? Looking through the docs, this I don't see how one would specify schema names there.

Comment: @jelford: The "NAME" element in the DATABASE is the schema.

Comment: And now I feel like a fool. Thanks for your patience.